# How to solve this SQL query identifier error in alias name?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, count, where-clause

I am trying to get count of event plan in table, but showing identifier error in count alias name event plan count.

IN ORACLE DATABASE(SQL)
[This is my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfOv0.png)

```
SELECT
  EventRequest.eventNo,
  EventRequest.dateHeld,
  count(*) AS eventPlanCount 
FROM EventRequest,eventplan 
where EventRequest.eventNo = Eventplan.eventNo and
Eventplan.workDate BETWEEN '01-DEC-2018' AND '31-DEC-2018'
GROUP BY EventRequest.eventNo
HAVING eventPlanCount > 1;
```

I am getting this error:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
SELECT
  EventRequest.eventNo,
  EventRequest.dateHeld,
  count(*) AS eventPlanCount
FROM EventRequest 
  where EventRequest.eventNo = Eventplan.eventNo and
Eventplan.workDate BETWEEN '01-DEC-2018' AND '31-DEC-2018'
GROUP BY EventRequest.eventNo
HAVING eventPlanCount > 1
Error at Command Line : 9 Column : 8
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "EVENTPLANCOUNT": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

i am new to this please help me!
THANKS IN ADVANCE!!..

Comment: Please use modern join syntax, available since SQL-92.

Comment: Here is documentation with examples. https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/sql-for-beginners-joins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
HAVING eventPlanCount > 1;
```

You can't use the alias here. Instead, you have to repeat the expression:

```
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```

Your query has other issues, namely:

- column `dateHeld` must be either repeated in the `group by` clause, or belong to an aggrgate function in the `select` clause
- you would rather use legitimate date literals rather than relying on implicit conversion of strings to date (also, half-open intervals are safer than `between`)
- you should use explicit joins instead of old-school implicit joins

So:

```
select r.eventno, r.dateheld, count(*) as eventplancount 
from eventrequest r
inner join eventplan p on p.eventno = r.eventno 
where p.workdate >= date '2018-01-01' and p.workdate < date '2019-01-01'
group by r.eventno, r.dateheld
having count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things about your query:

- You should use modern join syntax (SQL-92) instead of old joins. They are less error prone, easier to read, more powerful, and easier to debug. Fixed it in the query.
- It's easier to use table aliases. It help readability and it makes it easier to debug. I defined `r` an `p`.
- Columns not present in the `GROUP BY` clause should be aggregated. I added `r.dateHeld` to the `GROUP BY` clause.
- It's better to ensure you are using correct date comparisons. I forced Oracle to convert the strings to dates. Sometimes Oracle [wrongly] normalizes everything to `VARCHAR2`s when the operands are of a different type.
- In the `HAVING` clause I used `count(*)`.

With all of that your query can look like:

```
SELECT
  r.eventNo,
  r.dateHeld,
  count(*) AS eventPlanCount 
FROM EventRequest r
JOIN eventplan p ON r.eventNo = p.eventNo
WHERE p.workDate BETWEEN date '2018-12-01' AND date '2018-12-31'
GROUP BY r.eventNo, r.dateHeld
HAVING count(*) > 1
```